# macOS server - screensharing running with UID 0

Tags: macos, security, macos-sierra, screen-sharing

I run a mac server with a LAMP stack all installed via MacPorts, which I diligently keep up-to-date. The server is running macOS X Sierra, and I am less diligent about updating that, because the LAMP stack is completely independent.

However, today the server seized up and when I finally got in via ssh I found kernel_task running amok. It took a hard boot to get things back to normal.

I ran `top -o cpu` and I noticed that a task called screensharing was running. Odd, because I wasn't actually screensharing at the time, but I did have the service enabled for convenience.

I unloaded the service:

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.screensharing.plist
```

but then I started to wonder just what that had been all about. I reloaded the service and about five minutes later there it was again. This time I was able to see that the UID it was running as was 0. I quickly disabled it again.

My questions:

1. Is this a sign of foul play, or is this a quirk of the screensharing service?
2. If this is foul play, shouldn't disabling remote login by root prevent something like this?
3. If this is a known bug, has it been patched? I'm getting back in touch with `softwareupdate`.

Edit with mostly-joking follow-up question: where do I look to see if crypto-mining software has been installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Screen sharing is a part of remote management. Remote management requires root access (you are able to remotely change configurations that root is required to change). In order for screen sharing to provide GUI access for root, it too must have root access.

It is normal for Screen Sharing to be running as a root daemon (UID of zero).

This in and of itself does not indicate foul play.

Is this a known bug? I didn't find it listed (as a known bug) on Apple's website.

Would you be harmed by upgrading since the upgrade costs nothing? No. I run LAMP on High Sierra. Will your server support the upgrade to High Sierra? Without knowing the hardware, I can not answer that, but a trip to Apple's website will.

Comment: Thanks! Upgrading to High Sierra is impractical because it's a headless mac hundreds of miles away from me, but I'm glad to know that screensharing isn't giving Bad People root access.